# django and bootstrap modal with custom content

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to iterate through photo comments in bootstrap modal, photo which `src` I sent to modal.
Is there a way to put in bootstrap modal some of django information? From bootstrap docs (using jQuery):

```
<script>
$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
</script>
```

In that way I can put information from modal trigger to certain tag in modal, for example .modal-title or whatev. And I do it with some image that shows in modal:

```
$('#PhotoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
    $(".modal-photo").attr("src", image);
});
```

To that modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="PhotoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" role="document">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
        <div class='col'>
          <center><img class="modal-photo" src=""></center> #my custom img
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            # {% Add a comment loop %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that is element which triggers the modal:

```
<a class="overlay" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PhotoModal" src="{{ image }}">...</a>
```

My question is if I can do in modal some iteration. I have some class:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    who = models.OneToOneField(Profile, related_name='comments')
    image = models.OneToOneField(ProfileImages, related_name='comments')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I want do in modal something like this:

```
{% for comment in image.comments %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Where {{ image }} is the same object (or data in it) which triggered the modal

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking here? You can iterate over the comments as you've suggested provided you have an `image` variable in the context? What's not working?

Comment: In context I have queryset of images, and I want to show comments of image which triggered the modal

Comment: Ah I see. Create different modals for each of the images, and when you click on an image that will open the relevant modal for that image with the comments. If you take this approach just bear in mind that with a lot of images and comments you could be loading a lot of content onto the page and so it may be worth looking at loading the modals over AJAX.

Comment: I affraid I have to do this.. thanks